# My IIS website is not working on IP address

Tags: web, iis, server, localhost

I created an IIS website and bound it to both the localhost and my IP.
On localhost, It works fine but I cannot access it from my IP address.
I also tried if there was some problem with port and I found the port 139 working so i binded it to that but still problem continues.
Also, I use mobile hotspot for accessing internet.

Comment: Is the port forwarded in your firewall/router? You will not be able to access your website from the internet if your firewall/router does not allow it. Port 80 is standard for http.

Comment: What site binding are you using for this? Wrong bindings are common causes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background